# how to retain time range selected value in android

Tags: android

This is my custom dialog layout where we are displaying Date and Time range View:

```
<!-- activity_main.xml -->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- CalendarView -->
    <CalendarView
        android:id="@+id/calendarView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_8ssp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:text="Time Range" />

    <com.google.android.material.slider.RangeSlider
        android:id="@+id/range_slider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_8ssp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_8ssp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_start_range"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:text="0" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_end_range"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:text="23:59" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Additional Views -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="@dimen/_4sdp">

        <!-- Additional Button 1 -->

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/tv_back_to_today"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_8ssp"
            android:background="@drawable/layout_login"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/_16sdp"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/_16sdp"
            android:text="Back to today"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/yellow"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_13ssp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/box" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_confirm"
            style="@style/ButtonStyleForCameraSelectionProceedButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_8ssp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/_16sdp"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/_16sdp"
            android:text=" Confirm "
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_13ssp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This custom dialog Class :

```
import android.app.Dialog
import android.content.Context
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.Gravity
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.view.WindowManager
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi
import androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment
import com.rovedashcam.android.R
import com.rovedashcam.newmodeule.base.apppreferences.AppPreference
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.custom_date_picker_title.calendarView
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.custom_date_picker_title.range_slider
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.custom_date_picker_title.tv_back_to_today
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.custom_date_picker_title.tv_confirm
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.custom_date_picker_title.view.calendarView
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.time.LocalTime
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
import java.util.Calendar
import java.util.Date
import java.util.Locale

class TestCustomDatePickerDialog(
    val date: String, val startRange: Float, val endRange: Float,
    val appPreference: AppPreference
) :
    DialogFragment() {
    private var dialogClickListener: DialogClickListener? = null
    private var selectedDate = ""
    private var selectedStartRange = 0
    private var selectedEndRange = 24

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_date_picker_title, container, false)
        // Set the date in the CalendarView
        view.apply {
            val calendar = parseDateString(date)
            // Set the date in the CalendarView
            calendarView.date = calendar.timeInMillis
            val year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)
            // Get month (Note: Month values are 0-based, so January is 0)
            val month =
                calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1  // Adding 1 to adjust month value to start from 1
            // Get day of month
            val dayOfMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
            selectedDate = "$dayOfMonth-${month}-$year"
        }

        return view
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()

        // Set dialog window attributes for positioning
        val window = dialog?.window
        val layoutParams = window?.attributes
        layoutParams?.gravity = Gravity.TOP
        layoutParams?.y = 0  // Adjust the y-coordinate as needed
        layoutParams?.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT // Set width to match parent
        window?.attributes = layoutParams
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val startTime = startRange // Start time (in minutes since midnight)
        val endTime = (endRange * 60)// End time (in minutes since midnight)
        val timeInterval = 1f // Time interval (in minutes)

        range_slider.valueFrom = startTime
        range_slider.valueTo = endTime

        range_slider.stepSize = timeInterval
        range_slider.values = mutableListOf(startTime, endTime)
        // Set listener for CalendarView date change
        calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener { _, year, month, dayOfMonth ->
            // Handle CalendarView date change here
            selectedDate = "$dayOfMonth-${month + 1}-$year"
        }

        range_slider.addOnChangeListener { slider, _, _ ->
            if (appPreference.timeFormatPositionNewR24kOLD == "1") {
                val startMinute = range_slider.values[0].toInt()
                val endMinute = range_slider.values[1].toInt()
                val startHour = startMinute / 60
                val startMinuteRemainder = startMinute % 60
                val endHour = endMinute / 60
                val endMinuteRemainder = endMinute % 60

                val startTime = String.format(
                    "%02d:%02d %s",
                    if (startHour == 0 || startHour == 12) 12 else startHour % 12,
                    startMinuteRemainder,
                    if (startHour < 12) "AM" else "PM"
                )
                val endTime = String.format(
                    "%02d:%02d %s",
                    if (endHour == 0 || endHour == 12) 12 else endHour % 12,
                    endMinuteRemainder,
                    if (endHour < 12) "AM" else "PM"
                )
                Log.d("Time Interval", "$startTime--$endTime")
            } else {
                val minTime = convertTo24HourFormat(range_slider.values[0].toInt())
                val maxTime = convertTo24HourFormat(range_slider.values[1].toInt())
                Log.d("Time Interval", "$minTime--$maxTime")
            }


        }
        range_slider.setLabelFormatter { value ->
            val time = convertToTime(value.toInt())
            SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a", Locale.getDefault()).format(time)
        }

        // Set listeners for additional buttons
        tv_back_to_today.setOnClickListener {
            // Handle button1 click here
            dialogClickListener?.onBackToTodayClick(selectedDate)
            dialog?.dismiss()

        }

        tv_confirm.setOnClickListener {
            // Handle button2 click here
            dialog?.dismiss()
            val startTimeTimeRange = range_slider.values[0] / 60
            val endTimeRange = range_slider.values[1] / 60

            if (appPreference.timeFormatPositionNewR24kOLD == "0") {

                dialogClickListener?.onSelectedDateClick(
                    selectedDate,
                    getTimeStartTime12HourFormat(startTimeTimeRange),
                    getTimeStartTime12HourFormat(endTimeRange)
                )
            } else {
                dialogClickListener?.onSelectedDateClick(
                    selectedDate,
                    get24HourLocalTime(startTimeTimeRange),
                    get24HourLocalTime(endTimeRange)
                )
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        return super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState).apply {
//            setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false) // Prevent dismissing dialog when touched outside
        }
    }

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        // Ensure that the hosting activity implements the DialogClickListener interface
        if (context is DialogClickListener) {
            dialogClickListener = context
        } else {
            throw RuntimeException("$context must implement DialogClickListener")
        }
    }

    override fun onDetach() {
        super.onDetach()
        // Release the reference to the activity to avoid memory leaks
        dialogClickListener = null
    }

    interface DialogClickListener {
        fun onSelectedDateClick(date: String, startRange: LocalTime, endRange: LocalTime)
        fun onBackToTodayClick(date: String)
    }

    private fun parseDateString(dateString: String): Calendar {
        // Create a SimpleDateFormat for parsing the date string
        val dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy", Locale.getDefault())

        // Create a Calendar instance
        val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()

        // Parse the date string and set it in the Calendar object
        calendar.time = dateFormat.parse(dateString)!!

        return calendar
    }

    private fun convertToTime(minutes: Int): Date {
        val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, minutes / 60)
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minutes % 60)
        return calendar.time
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private fun convertTo24HourFormat(hours: Int): String {
        val normalizedHours = hours % 24 // Ensure the hour value is within the valid range
        val time = LocalTime.of(normalizedHours, 0)
        val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm")
        return time.format(formatter)
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private fun getTimeStartTime12HourFormat(timeInput: Float): LocalTime {
        val hours = timeInput.toInt()
        val minutes = ((timeInput - hours) * 60).toInt()
        // Parse the input time string into a LocalTime object
        return LocalTime.of(hours % 12, minutes)
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private fun get24HourLocalTime(timeInput: Float): LocalTime {
        val hours = timeInput.toInt()
        val minutes = ((timeInput - hours) * 60).toInt()
        return LocalTime.of(hours, minutes)
    }
}
```

This activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/range_slider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/reactangle_bg"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="@dimen/_8sdp"
        android:text="Click Me" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

This is MainActivity Class

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.rovedashcam.android.R
import com.rovedashcam.newmodeule.base.apppreferences.AppPreference
import com.rovedashcam.newmodeule.base.apppreferences.AppPreferenceImpl
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.range_slider
import java.time.LocalTime

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), TestCustomDatePickerDialog.DialogClickListener {

    private lateinit var appPreference: AppPreference

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        appPreference = AppPreferenceImpl(this)

        // Example values to retain
        val date = "20 March 2024"
        var startRange = 0f // Example start range value
        var endRange = 24f // Example end range value
        // Show the CustomDatePickerDialog with the example values
        range_slider.setOnClickListener {
            showCustomDatePickerDialog(date, startRange, endRange)
        }

    }

    private fun showCustomDatePickerDialog(date: String, startRange: Float, endRange: Float) {
        val dialog = TestCustomDatePickerDialog(date, startRange, endRange, appPreference)
        dialog.show(supportFragmentManager, "CustomDatePickerDialog")
    }

    override fun onSelectedDateClick(date: String, startRange: LocalTime, endRange: LocalTime) {
    }

    override fun onBackToTodayClick(date: String) {
    }
}
```

Using above code i am able to display Date and Time range view and we are able to selected value in Local Time .
But  I am trying to retain value for Time range i.e when i click on button and open Popup then if we select 2am to 6 pm and close Popup then again we open popup then same value it should pick in time range slider .

can any one please suggest or help how we can do this .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the issue is related to the AppPreferece being destroyed due to a configuration change on the Activity.

Looks like you're recreating the AppPreferences each time on OnCreate, and each time you create a new one, the original state is lost.

You should use a ViewModel and store the AppPreference inside it, so that the view model will handle the state and it can survive configuration changes.

Or you can save the AppPreference info inside a Bundle then reload it. But for large objects like this you can either Serialise it as a Parcelable object, or just store in a view model. View model is much easier.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/ViewModel